# Iterating over array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs.I am having one select box.In select i am displaying all the exercise names by doing ng-repeat where multiple exercise names can be selected.

Here is my **HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Selct Exercises</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" multiple>
        <option data-ng-repeat="exercise in exercises" value="
        {{exercise}}" data-ng-checked="selection.indexOf(exercise) > -1" data-ng-click="toggleSelectionExercise(exercise)">
            {{exercise.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now after selecting multiple exercise names onclick i am calling this function

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.parameterTest = [];
$scope.parameter1 = [];
var exercise = [];
$scope.toggleSelectionExercise = function
toggleSelection(exercise) {
  var idx = $scope.parameterTest.indexOf(exercise);
  if (idx > -1) {
    $scope.parameterTest.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
    console.log(exercise);
    $scope.parameterTest.push(exercise);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.parameterTest.length; i++) {
      var parameter1 = {
        "exid": exercise._id,
        "modify": 0,
        "sets": exercise.sets,
        "reps": exercise.reps,
        "rest_duration": 60,
        "ord": 0
      };
      /*Setting in json format and storing in parameter1*/
      $scope.parameterTest[i] = parameter1;
      /*parameter1 value passing to $scope.parameterTest[i]*/
      console.log($scope.parameterTest[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am passing exercise object to the function.From the exercise object I am setting values and passing in JSON format and storing it in variable `parameter1`.

I want to set every object selected in dropdown to be set in this format thats why I am iterating every object and setting the format and value.

But now if I select one option from dropdown it is displaying that object and setting the correct value and format.But if i select multiple options then for 2 options it is displaying like this

First object value set in JSON Format
Object `{exid: "59bc2dbc53bdcb7171732eab", modify: 0, sets: 3, reps: Array[6], rest_duration: 60…}`

Second object value set in JSON Format 
Object `{exid: "59bc2d9453bdcb7171732eaa", modify: 0, sets: 3, reps: Array[6], rest_duration: 60…}`

Second option displaying second time
Object `{exid: "59bc2d9453bdcb7171732eaa", modify: 0, sets: 3, reps: Array[6], rest_duration: 60…}`

If I select two options it is displaying first object once and second object twice.

I dont know where I am doing wrong. Am I doing looping correctly?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve inside the else block by pushing the "exercise" object to   parameterTest and again trying to modify it inside an array ?

Comment: I am just pushing it into one array called parameterTest and iterating in for loop and assigning the json format for every object and passing to parameterTest[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be what you are doing is wrong.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/) for working sample code

I'm little confused about the code in "**else**" block where you push the "**exercise**" object to "**$scope.parameterTest**" array then iterate and assign a different object obtain from the same "**exercise**" object to the "**$scope.parameterTest**" array.

And I think where you check for existing "**exercise**" object in the "**$scope.parameterTest**" is wrong, since you change the "exercise" object saved in the "**$scope.parameterTest**" from assigning the "**parameter1**" value.

```
$scope.parameterTest[i] = parameter1;
```

If you really need to modify the exercise object then change

```
var idx = $scope.parameterTest.indexOf(exercise);
```

to

```
var exerciseItemFoundInArray = false;
var exerciseItemFoundIndex = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.parameterTest.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.parameterTest[i].exid == exercise._id) {
        exerciseItemFoundInArray = true;
        exerciseItemFoundIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (exerciseItemFoundInArray == true && exerciseItemFoundIndex != -1) 
{
    $scope.parameterTest.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

or to find the index use below this is supported by all most all the browsers(IE - 12, Chrome 45 etc)

```
var idx = $scope.parameterTest.findindex((item)=> {return item.exid == exercise._id});
```

And I have removed your "for" loop since it is unnecessary. The revised code for function "toggleExerciseSelection"

```
$scope.toggleSelectionExercise = function
toggleSelection(exercise) {
    var exerciseItemFoundInArray = false;
    var exerciseItemFoundIndex = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.parameterTest.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.parameterTest[i].exid == exercise._id) {
            exerciseItemFoundInArray = true;
            exerciseItemFoundIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (exerciseItemFoundInArray == true && exerciseItemFoundIndex != -1) 
    {
        $scope.parameterTest.splice(exerciseItemFoundIndex, 1);
        console.log( $scope.parameterTest);
    } else {
        var parameter1 = {
            "exid": exercise._id,
            "modify": 0,
            "sets": exercise.sets,
            "reps": exercise.reps,
            "rest_duration": 60,
            "ord": 0
        };
        $scope.parameterTest.push(parameter1);
        console.log( $scope.parameterTest);
    }
};
```

Comment: If i select three options then only third option is getting passed and also it is passing three times.1st and 2nd selected options are not getting passed

Comment: just to clarify if you select a previously selected option, you want to remove that right ?

Comment: I have added some edits. let me know the error if it is not working

Comment: Yea i want to remove the element if i select it twice.

Comment: Do i need to change anything in my html?And one more thing is where can i specify Json format in the code.var parameter1 = {
        "exid": exercise._id,
        "modify": 0,
        "sets": exercise.sets,
        "reps": exercise.reps,
        "rest_duration": 60,
        "ord": 0
      };

Comment: I need to assign this json values for the objects selected in dropdown and pass it as a variable to web api.

Comment: In the exercise object i have 10 parameters.id,name,sets,reps,rest_duration etc.This exercise object id i need to set to exid,reps to reps,sets to sets and pass it as json.But now if i select three options the third option is getting passed three times.!st and second are not setting

Comment: It is displaying idx is not defined

Comment: Hello I have created a jsfiddle for this. Please check. I have corrected your function check the console log when you are checking the fiddle

Comment: Woww.You are just amazing bro.You saved my day.Thank you very much.Everything is working now..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this ng-change and ng-model for select
In HTML

```
<select ng-model="is_checked" ng-change="hey(is_checked)" multiple>
  <option ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

In Controller  is_checked returns the option clicked check if the option is already in list if not add it else splice it.

```
$scope.checkedvalues = [];
$scope.hey = function(is_checked){
    var option = $scope.checkedvalues.indexOf(is_checked);
    // if option in list 
        $scope.checkedvalues.splice(option,1);
    }else{
        $scope.checkedvalues.push(is_checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: But i want exercise object in controller function because i need to set values from exercise object to json format

Comment: pass the object to value in option that is what you get in ng-model.

Comment: Can u tell what condition i have to give in "if" inside function

Comment: I hope this will help you https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/50721fce7c7091000201e56a
We have to check if a value of a key in dic exists in the list if yes then get to know the index of the element/object and delete it.